# Is there an absolutely continuous function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, approximation-theory

Is there an absolutely continuous function $f$ satisfying
$$
|f(x+\delta)+f(x-\delta)-2f(x)|\leq \mbox{const}\frac{|\delta|}{\log \frac{1}{|\delta|}},\,\,\, |\delta|<1,  
$$
which is not $C^{1}$?

Comment: What about the function that maps $x$ to 0 if $x=0$, or else to $\frac{|x|}{\log\frac{1}{|x|}}$?

Comment: Dear Ravi, maybe you could add some motivation for this question, together with some general information on related known facts.

Comment: This question seems more appropriate for MSE than MO.

Comment: Is it clear that it must be differentiable?

Comment: @ Delio M. No. $x=\delta=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @PietroMajer. A continuous function  $f:J\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on an open interval $J$ satisfies the Zygmund(=$C^Z$) (or little Zygmund(=$C^z$)) condition if 
$$f(x+\delta)+f(x-\delta)-2f(x)=O(|\delta|)$$
(...or $=o(|\delta|)$) for all $x\in J$ and sufficiently small $\delta$.

Comment: Note that the class $C^Z$ wider than the class of Lipschitz functions. Indeed, there exists functions $f\in C^Z$ which are nowhere differentiable
and functions $f\in C^z$ differentiable in a set of measure zero only. (see. [Trigonometric Series](http://carlossicoli.free.fr/Z/Zygmund_A.-Trigonometric_Series,_Third_Edition,_Volume_I_&_II_Combined_(Cambridge_Mathematical_Library)-Cambridge_University_Press(2002).pdf)). So, I need an example which is satisfying $\leq\frac{|\delta|}{\log\frac{1}{|\delta|}}$ and absolutely continuous but not $C^1$.

Comment: @user400001. Yes it is clear.

Comment: @StGeorg. Could you help me.